# Imported products in Magento 1.7 are not appearing

Tags: magento, magento-1.4, magento-1.7

I'm trying to transfer prodcuts from Magento 1.4.0.2 (Site-A) into Mangeto 1.7.0.1 (Site-B).

I've configured an export profile in Site-A with these field mappings:

```
sku | name | short_description | weight | price | type | description | attribute_set | tax_class_id
```

After running this profile I've got an `export_all_products.csv` file. I imported it into Site-B. (I had setup Site-B with an Import All Products Dataflow Profile which maps the filed the same way.)

After importing, I refreshed all the indexes, but there are still no products  under "Catalog → Manage Products".

Why are the products not appearing?

(I suspect this is because `store B` has two websites and `store A` has only one. Neither one of the websites has the same name.)

Does the store name information need to be added to each product in the exported CSV?

Comment: I think you need to specify the `website` column. The products in grid would not show up, if they are not associated with current website

Comment: how do I specify this colmun? do I manually include it in the CSV? and if so what value should it contain? the website name, website ID? Referencing the websites on `site A` or on `site B`? I've tried to include the column in the export from `site A` but it still didn't work

Comment: yes, you should manually include the column in CSV file, it should contain the website_code of the Website you want to associate products with, typically - the base website (code 'base')

Comment: didn't work out, same problem..

Comment: I'm sorry, I've misled you! I've checked the profile, and the column should be named "**websites**" - not website!

Comment: it's not that, i didn't use the first row of the CSV to enter labels..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apparently it was a matter of having the required columns + a few extras. 
Magento requires these 10 columns to be present in the CSV file, otherwise the import won't be valid:

1. type
2. attribute_set
3. tax_class_id
4. status
5. weight
6. sku
7. name
8. price
9. description
10. short_description

From [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/3_-_store_setup_and_management/import_export/export_tool#important_notes_about_importing_products)

If you want the product to be *order-able* you have to add:

- website
- category_ids
- is_in_stock

Comment: Without '_product_website' option set in import my Magento (1.9.0.1) hasn't display product until I didn't enter to 'Manage Product' edition and clicked 'save' without any changes.

Comment: @Bogdan, Instead of using *System→Import/Export→Dataflowprofiles*, Why don't you use the *System→Import/Export→Import* and   *System→Import/Export→Export* instead? There are much better debugging messages there and they will tell you exactly which columns have errors / are missing.

Answer (score 4):

To see if the problem is not setting the correct store/website you can do this:

1) Login to Magento admin, and goto product listing.

2) click select all

3) click update attributes - Select websites / stores from the left hand side and apply.

this will help narrow down the issue, if not solve it.

Comment: your suggestions apply to `site A` or `site B`? On the websites tab, there are 2 options: `Add Product To Websites` and `Remove Product From Websites` none of them are checked. What do I have to click apply to? should I check of the two options or what? I don't understand how does updating attributes help me with the import problem...

Comment: I run into the same problem with Magento 1.13.1.0 and your solution worked well. Thank you very much.

Comment: You are genius mate, was googling from a week and your solution helped me. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

We ran into a similar problem like this recently and found a problem with special character in this case the Registered Trademark Symbol "®" placed into the .csv

Not sure if this is contributing to the issue but removing the special characters solved the issue. Hope this helps.

Comment: I had the same issue but with a © symbol

Comment: @foiseworth, if even © and ® don't work, I wonder how non-English Magento sites are coping.......

Answer (score 1):

On an unrelated note, ensure that when you are running a dataflow profile, you have selected "Import product stocks" and not "Import all products" in the dataflow profiles.

Comment: What's the difference between these two?

Answer (score -1):

Had this problem exporting from OpenOffice Calc, needed to set to export in UTF-8, probably also because of special characters.